# Angular custom directive repeats the element in angular 5

Tags: angular

I want to build an directive in that directive an array of elements will be there and by binding that directive on any element the element should repeat the number of times the array has in suppose if array has 3 elements by binding directive to element element will repeat 3 times please help and provide basic idea because i am beginner to it i want to acheive this in angular 5

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you. Should the repeated elements contain the content of the array elements?

Comment: No the content should be from diffrent component like <hello *myDirectiveFor name="{{ name }}"></hello> like this so if i attached my directive on this element content should be repeated number of times the array elements has hello is my diffrent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure, if I understand you (punctuation marks would probably help).

Why not use ngFor?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p *ngFor="let elem of arr">I'm an element!</p>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = [1,2,3];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Alexander but i want to do this scenario with custom directive not with built in ngFor directive

Comment: my custom directive should work as ngFor i hope now you are clear about my issue

Comment: So you want to create a custom directive that emulates the built-in structural directive ngFor? Did I get that right? Or do you want to create a custom component with this functionality baked in?

Comment: Yes you are right i want to create a custom directive that emulates the built-in structural directive ngFor

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive file:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myFor]' })
export class ForDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) { }

  @Input() set myFor((arr: any[]) {
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }
}
```

Add an array to your component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = [1,2,3];

  getArr() {
    return this.arr;
  }
}
```

Add the directive to your template:

```
<p *myFor="getArr()">
  Test
</p>
```

Register the directive at the appropriate places.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/emulate-ngfor-directive-in-angular

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander but can you tell me how can i get the value dynamically from array for Example:-Myarr=['angular1','angular2'] now only prints "Test" based on array size but if i want to do this way like Test angular1 and Test angular2 is it possible if i want to print array values dynamically number of times based on array size is it possible? that what i actually needs